Setting Password protection for NFC Tag ISO 14443
I am trying to create a feature for an app where we store text information on an NFC tag. The information is started as text and is ~128 bytes.
The issue is that I want to add password protection to the tag so that other people cannot write to it.
for reference, the tag I am using is the one specified in this document:  https://resourcewebsite.singoo.cc/15307900505930426/en/pdf/1670211742605/FM11NT021_sds_eng.pdf
I am also using react-native and react-native-nfc-manger for this project.
Currently, when I use the setPassword function, it seems like the password and pack commands work, but then I get a "Connection loss" to the tag before it seems the auth0 wirte is completed.
When I go to write to the tag, the pack comes back as [0, 0] inn either the writeNdefWithPass or the authenticatePassword functions.
Does anyone see where I might be going wrong? I'm not sure if the messages are formatted correctly or if I am writing to the right addresses. the code is below:
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */



// important link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAS-DvNUFck&t=2591s
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import type {PropsWithChildren} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';

import NfcManager, {NfcTech, NfcEvents, Ndef} from 'react-native-nfc-manager';
// Pre-step, call this before any NFC operations
NfcManager.start();


function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = React.useState({
    serialnumber: '',
    codeVersion: '',
    Date: '',
    setting1: '',
    setting2: '',
    setting3: '',
    setting4: '',

  });

  const[outputs , setOutputs] = React.useState({
    serialnumber: '',
    codeVersion: '',
    Date: '',
    setting1: '',
    setting2: '',
    setting3: '',
    setting4: '',
  });

  const showReadAlert = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      "NFC Action Required",
      "Please bring your phone near the receiver and press ok to read the Values from the receiver",
      [
        { text: "Cancel", style: "cancel" },
        { text: "OK", onPress: readNdef }
      ]
    );
  };

  const showWriteAlert = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      "NFC Action Required",
      "Please bring your phone near the receiver and press ok to write the Values to the receiver",
      [
        { text: "Cancel", style: "cancel" },
        { text: "OK", onPress: writeNdef }
      ]
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function checkNfc(){
      const supported = await NfcManager.isSupported();
      console.log('NFC Supported:', supported);
      if (supported) {
        await NfcManager.start();
        console.log('NFC started');
      }
    }
    checkNfc();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() =>{
    console.log(outputs)

  }, [outputs])

  const getInputString = () =>{
    console.log("Getting input string")
    return 'SN:' + inputs.serialnumber + ', ' + 'RX:' + inputs.codeVersion + ', ' + 'Date:' + inputs.Date + ', ' + 'S1:' + inputs.setting1 + ', ' + 'S2:' + inputs.setting2 + ', ' + 'S3:' + inputs.setting3 + ', ' + 'S4:' + inputs.setting4;
  }

  const proccessPayload = (payload) => {
    console.log("Processing payload")
    let payloadString = Ndef.text.decodePayload(payload);
    let payloadArray = payloadString.split(', ');
    let serialnumber = payloadArray[0].split(':');
    let codeVersion = payloadArray[1].split(':');
    let Date = payloadArray[2].split(':');
    let setting1 = payloadArray[3].split(':');
    let setting2 = payloadArray[4].split(':');
    let setting3 = payloadArray[5].split(':');
    let setting4 = payloadArray[6].split(':');
    setOutputs({
      serialnumber: serialnumber[1],
      codeVersion: codeVersion[1],
      Date: Date[1],
      setting1: setting1[1],
      setting2: setting2[1],
      setting3: setting3[1],
      setting4: setting4[1],
    });
    console.log(outputs)
  }

  async function readNdef() {
    console.log('readNdef');
    
    try {
      // register for the NFC tag with NDEF in it
      await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.Ndef);
      // the resolved tag object will contain `ndefMessage` property
      const tag = await NfcManager.getTag();
      console.warn('Tag found', tag);
      proccessPayload(tag.ndefMessage[0].payload);
    } catch (ex) {
      console.warn('Oops!', ex);
    } finally {
      // stop the nfc scanning
      NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest();
    }
  }

  async function writeNdef() {
    console.log('writeNdef');
    let result = false;
  
    try {
      // STEP 1
      await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.Ndef);
  
      const bytes = Ndef.encodeMessage([Ndef.textRecord(getInputString())]);
  
      if (bytes) {
        await NfcManager.ndefHandler // STEP 2
          .writeNdefMessage(bytes); // STEP 3
        result = true;
      }
    } catch (ex) {
      console.warn(ex);
    } finally {
      // STEP 4
      NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest();
    }
  
    return result;
  }

  async function writeNdefWithPass() {
    console.log('writeNdefwithpass');
    let result = false;
  
    try {
      // STEP 1: Request NFC technology (NfcA or IsoDep)
      await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.NfcA);  // Use NfcA for FM11NT021
      
      const password = [0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74];  // Your 4-byte password
      console.log("Authenticating with password...");
      
      // Build the PWD_AUTH command (0x1B)
      const pwdAuthCommand = [
        0x1B,              // Command code for PWD_AUTH
        ...password,       // 4-byte password
      ];
  
      // Send the PWD_AUTH command
      const response = await NfcManager.nfcAHandler.transceive(pwdAuthCommand);
      console.log("PWD_AUTH Response:", response);
  
      // Extract the PACK (first 2 bytes of the response)
      const packResponse = response.slice(0, 2);
      const expectedPack = [0x67, 0x6f];  // Replace with your actual stored PACK value
  
      if (JSON.stringify(packResponse) === JSON.stringify(expectedPack)) {
        console.log('Password authenticated successfully. Writing data...');
  
        // STEP 2: Write data to the NFC tag
        const bytes = Ndef.encodeMessage([Ndef.textRecord(getInputString())]);
        if (bytes) {
          await NfcManager.ndefHandler.writeNdefMessage(bytes);  // STEP 3: Write NDEF data
          result = true;
          console.log("Data written successfully.");
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Password authentication failed. Writing aborted.');
      }
    } catch (ex) {
      console.warn('Error:', ex);
    } finally {
      // STEP 4: Cancel NFC technology request
      NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest();
    }
  
    return result;
  }

  // 74 65 73 74
  async function setPassword() {
    try {
      // STEP 1: Request NFC technology
      // STEP 2: send PWD 
      await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.Ndef);
      // const isoDep = await NfcManager.getTag();
      const password = [0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74]; // Your 4-byte password
      const pack = [0x67, 0x6f]; // Your 2-byte PACK value
      const auth0 = 0x04;  // Protect starting from page 4

      const writePasswordCMD = [
        0xA2,  // WRITE command
        0x2B,  // PWD memory address
        ...password,
      ]

      const writePackCMD = [
        0xA2,  // WRITE command
        0x2C,  // PACK memory address
        ...pack,
      ]

      const writeAuth0CMD = [
        0xA2,  // WRITE command
        0x29,  // AUTH0 memory address
        auth0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 // Lock all pages starting from page 4
      ]

      await NfcManager.nfcAHandler.transceive(writePasswordCMD);
      await NfcManager.nfcAHandler.transceive(writePackCMD);
      await NfcManager.nfcAHandler.transceive(writeAuth0CMD);

    } catch (ex) {
      console.warn(ex);
    } finally {
      // STEP 3: Cancel the NFC technology request
      NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest();
    }
  }

  async function authenticatePassword() {
    try {
      // Request NFC technology (IsoDep for FM11NT021)
      await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.Ndef);
  
      const isoDep = await NfcManager.getTag();
      const password = [0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74]; // Your 4-byte password
      console.log("auth password 1")
      // Build the PWD_AUTH command (0x1B)
      const pwdAuthCommand = [
        0x1B,             // Command code for PWD_AUTH
        ...password,      // 4-byte password
      ];
  
      // Send the command and get the response
      const response = await NfcManager.nfcAHandler.transceive(pwdAuthCommand);
      console.log("auth password 1")
      console.log('PWD_AUTH Response:', response);
  
      // Compare with the PACK to confirm successful authentication
      const PACK = response.slice(0, 2); // Should match the stored PACK
  
    } catch (ex) {
      console.warn(ex);
    } finally {
      // Close the connection
      NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest();
    }
  }
  

  return (
  <ScrollView>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      placeholder="Serial Number"
      value={inputs.serialnumber}
      maxLength={8}
      onChangeText={(text) => setInputs({ ...inputs, serialnumber: text })}
    />
    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      placeholder="Code Version"
      value={inputs.codeVersion}
      maxLength={4}
      onChangeText={(text) => setInputs({ ...inputs, codeVersion: text })}
    />
    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      placeholder="Date"
      value={inputs.Date}
      maxLength={10}
      onChangeText={(text) => setInputs({ ...inputs, Date: text })}
    />
    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      placeholder="Setting 1"
      value={inputs.setting1}
      maxLength={2}
      onChangeText={(text) => setInputs({ ...inputs, setting1: text })}
    />
    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      placeholder="Setting 2"
      value={inputs.setting2}
      maxLength={2}
      onChangeText={(text) => setInputs({ ...inputs, setting2: text })}
    />
    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      placeholder="Setting 3"
      value={inputs.setting3}
      maxLength={2}
      onChangeText={(text) => setInputs({ ...inputs, setting3: text })}
    />
    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      placeholder="Setting 4"
      value={inputs.setting4}
      maxLength={2}
      onChangeText={(text) => setInputs({ ...inputs, setting4: text })}
    />
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={Platform.OS == 'android' ? showWriteAlert :writeNdef}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Write to NFC tag</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={Platform.OS == 'android' ? showWriteAlert :writeNdefWithPass}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Write to NFC tag with pass</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={Platform.OS == 'android' ? showReadAlert :readNdef}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Read NFC Tag</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={Platform.OS == 'android' ? setPassword : setPassword}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Set Password (test)</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={Platform.OS == 'android' ? authenticatePassword : authenticatePassword}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Test Password (test)</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity> 
    
    <View>
      <View style={styles.displayBox}>
        <Text style = {styles.outTitle}> last Read Output</Text>
        <Text>Serial Number: {outputs.serialnumber}</Text>
        <Text>Code Version: {outputs.codeVersion}</Text>
        <Text>Date: {outputs.Date}</Text>
        <Text>Setting 1: {outputs.setting1}</Text>
        <Text>Setting 2: {outputs.setting2}</Text>
        <Text>Setting 3: {outputs.setting3}</Text>
        <Text>Setting 4: {outputs.setting4}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
  </ScrollView>
  );
}


export default App;


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop:10,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  input: {
    color: 'white',
    height: 40,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 4,
    marginBottom: 12,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    width: '80%',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#007BFF',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginTop: 10,
    width: '80%',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  wrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor:'blue',
    width: '80%',
    height: '20%',
  },
  displayBox:{
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom:30,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  outTitle:{
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    margin: 20
  }
});


It might be a similar issue to https://stackoverflow.com/q/78834775/2373819 and swapping Tag Technology classes, but that has not answer.

From the tags data sheet I can't clearly see what NFC technologies are supported by the tag (I don't mean Forum 2 compatible..). As the tag description looks very similar to an NXP NTAG213 tag I assume that the tag supports NfcA, Mifare Ultralight and NDEF technologies. To be for sure: please use the Android app "NXP TagInfo" to get the tech classes (after reading the tag on tab "Full Scan" -> TAG. If the tag supports NfcA you need to run the "Write AuthX"  using this tech class. The NDEF class can be used only for modifying the stored NDEF message on the tag.
